# Not able to deliver the mail in canvas lms? What configuration setting i am missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas-lms

This is my outgoing_mail.yml files
If click on the forgot password link It is showing in the delayed_job.log
My email is deliver got stuck please help me.

```
production: 
    address: "smtp.gmail.com" 
    port: "587" 
    user_name: "xxxxxx@gmail.com" 
    password: "password" 
    authentication: "plain" # plain, login, or cram_md5 
    domain: "domain_name.com" 
    outgoing_address: "xxxxxx@gmail.com" 
    default_name: "Instructure Canvas"
```

Comment: Check your mail configuration in config/environments/production.rb with the given answer below

Comment: Did you ever work on canvas lms? @Gabbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My SMTP settings are right but the in site admin settings there is feature option section there is an option "Use remote service for notifications"  is No so is if you use remote service like mailer etc. this option turns into off.
And It's working fine.

[image: feature option settings]

Answer (score 1):

In `config/environments/production.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'your host', port: 'xxx' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => 'abc.com',
      :user_name => "xxxx@mail.com",
      :password => "xxxx",
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Ok let me check once i have already tried similar solution but id does not work thanks for your valuable time @Gabbar